# cvSVD Error calculating EigenValues

Tags: opencv

I am facing a problem with cvSVD method. I am trying to calculate EigenValues and EigenVectors for symmetric square matrices.

I applied it on a (5*5) matrix and I got correct answers. But when I apply it on a (3*3) matrices the EigenValues are wrong!

```
CvMat* matt = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
cvZero(matt);

CV_MAT_ELEM( *matt, float, 0, 0 ) = 1.0;
CV_MAT_ELEM( *matt, float, 0, 1 ) = 3.0;
CV_MAT_ELEM( *matt, float, 0, 2 ) = 5.0;

CV_MAT_ELEM( *matt, float, 1, 0 ) = 0.142857;
CV_MAT_ELEM( *matt, float, 1, 1 ) = 1.0;
CV_MAT_ELEM( *matt, float, 1, 2 ) = 1.0;

CV_MAT_ELEM( *matt, float, 2, 0 ) = 0.111111;
CV_MAT_ELEM( *matt, float, 2, 1 ) = 0.2;
CV_MAT_ELEM( *matt, float, 2, 2 ) = 1.0;

CvMat* Ut  = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* Dt  = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* Vt  = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* Resultt  = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
cvSVD(matt, Dt, Ut, Vt, CV_32FC1); // A = U D V^T
cvMatMul(Ut,Vt,Resultt);

cout<<"EigenValues"<<endl;
cout<<cvmGet(Dt,0,0)<<endl;
cout<<cvmGet(Dt,1,1)<<endl;
cout<<cvmGet(Dt,2,2)<<endl;

The output is:
EigenValues
6.15042
0.485238
0.0978629

The correct output is:
2.2509
0.2719
0.4771
```

I applied the SAME way on the (5*5) matrix and the output was correct. Am I missing something? any suggestions?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in OpenCV, as you can see here https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1370
and it is fixed in the latest OpenCV build.

You can download it and compile it yourself, following the instructions here:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide